# Webpack remove dashes in [name]

Tags: webpack

I have following loader in webpack:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
    loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
}
```

I want to replace the dashes in [name]. How to do?

```
my-image.png => myimage.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a `customInterpolateName` function to your webpack config and change the filename there.

```
module.exports = {
  customInterpolateName: function (loaderContext, name, options) {
    // access loaderContext via this (e.g. loaderContext.context)
    return loaderContext.replace(/-/g, '');
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/90#issuecomment-257981311

Comment: With webpack2+ (I believe) a slight modification to this pattern is required. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578418/is-it-possible-to-strip-special-characters-from-filenames-in-webpack/45595171#45595171