# Is it possible to strip special characters from filenames in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamics-crm

Long story short, I cannot have certain characters like hyphens in our asset filenames. I'm not having the best of luck parsing through webpack documentation to figure out if it is possible to rename a file using a regex or something similar so I can strip out any hyphens from 3rd party packages where I do not control the source filename.

My super naive example would be something like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: `url-loader?limit=${ASSETS_LIMIT}&name=fonts/[name.replace(/-/)].[ext]`
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible or how one would approach this requirement? Thanks!

Comment: could this https://www.npmjs.com/package/rename-loader be of any help for you?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Dynamics CRM? If not, maybe remove the tag...

Comment: @Aron yes, Dynamics CRM is what is restricting the filename.

Comment: Thanks. Are you loading these files into CRM as web resources?

Comment: @Unlockedluca couldn't seem to get anything using the underlying `loader-utils`'s `regExp` option to work. My build will get to 95% (emitting) and then freeze for at least 5-10+ minutes on a build that usually takes 15-20s. Thanks tho!

Comment: @Aron yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this riddle appears to be found in the `customInterpolateName` loader option. With webpack@v3.4.1 the below was my end result for removing a hyphen.

This was the key tidbit:

```
plugins: [
    // ... other plugins ...
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            customInterpolateName: (loaderContext) => {
                return loaderContext.replace(/-/g, '');
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Here's a more complete example to give some context (note: the `.css` was appended to the font filenames intentionally as a workaround for yet another web resource name restriction in Dynamics CRM):

```
module.exports = {
    // ... other config ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // ... other loaders ...
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: `url-loader?limit=${ASSETS_LIMIT}&name=fonts/[name].[ext].css`
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // ... other plugins ...
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                customInterpolateName: (loaderContext) => {
                    return loaderContext.replace(/-/g, '');
                }
            }
        })
    ]
};
```